# Skip hidden files when copying with Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is my current script...

```
copy '.\Alfresco Development Config Files\*' C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes -rec -force
```

How would I change that so hidden files are skipped?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adverse to using a native command, then

```
robocopy '.\Alfresco Development Config Files' C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes /s /XA:H
```

(Possibly need to give a full path for the source, as current PowerShell directory and current working directory of the process are not the same thing (and cannot be, in the general case)).

Fixing the previous PowerShell variant would probably be possible but cumbersome.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work if you have child folders. It picks up all of the files, but dumps them into one folder.

Answer (score -1):

There's probably more succinct way to go about it, but maybe this will help:

```
$NonHiddenObjects = Compare -IncludeEqual `
 -Diff (Dir ".\Alfresco Development Config Files\" -Rec -Force | Select -Exp FullName) `
 -Ref  (Dir ".\Alfresco Development Config Files\" -Rec | Select -Exp FullName) `
 | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} `
 | Select -Exp InputObject

copy $NonHiddenObjects C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes -force
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work if you have child folders. It picks up all of the files, but dumps them into one folder.